# Maven Plugin conflict

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, cucumber-jvm, test-reporting

What all i want to do is run test in phase integration-test and then generate report.
by mvn verify

But only test are executed report never runs. When i comment first plugin then other is executed. Any idea how to fix it?

I have below in my pom

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                        <executableDependency>
                            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                        </executableDependency>
                        <mainClass>cucumber.api.cli.Main</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>target/test-classes/feature</argument>
                            <agrument>--glue</agrument>
                            <argument>integration</argument>
                            <argument>src\test\java</argument>
                            <argument>--plugin</argument>
                            <argument>pretty</argument>
                            <argument>--plugin</argument>
                            <argument>html:target/cucumber-report</argument>
                            <argument>--plugin</argument>
                            <argument>json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json</argument>
                            <argument>--tags</argument>
                            <argument>~@ignore</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>poc.selenium.it</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-report</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        <enableFlashCharts>true</enableFlashCharts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that `cucumber.api.cli.Main` [calls `System.exit`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/cli/Main.java#L19) and therefore terminates the Maven process before the other plugin gets to be executed.

One way to fix the problem would be to use the `exec` goal of the `exec-maven-plugin`, rather than the `java` goal, as it runs in a separate process.

However, a better (and easier) solution is to define a JUnit test that will configure and run your cucumber tests, for example:

```java
package integration;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json")
public class RunTest {
}
```

You can then use either the `maven-surefire-plugin` or the `maven-failsafe-plugin` plugin to execute that test. The `maven-cucumber-reporting` plugin will then execute successfully and create the report.

You can see this in action on a [github branch I have just pushed](https://github.com/tychobrailleur/cucumber-jvm-examples/blob/exec-plugin/java-example/pom.xml).

Comment: Thanks for clear answer, that worked for me. was so frustrated!!